# Как правильно использовать функцию в аргументе другой функции?

Tags: php, wordpress, bbpress

WordPress, плагин bbPress

Есть функция, которая возвращает, к примеру, логин или id пользователя:

```
bbp_user_login()
```

Как с её помощью можно вытащить дату регистрации пользователя, чтобы добавить в профиль?

Так как знаний php нет, я думал, что результат функции можно использовать как аргумент другой функции. Например, вот так:

```
$user_log = get_user_by('Login', bbp_user_login());
$user_reg = $user_log->user_registered;
```

Но так не работает....

Как можно выполнить данную задачу?

Comment: Что такое "хук"? И что именно "не работает"?

Comment: Это не хук вообще, а функция.

Comment: Разберитесь, что возвращает bbp_user_login(). Наверняка не строку, а массив. В этом и проблема.

Comment: Ваша проблема в том, что такой функции `bbp_user_login()` не существует в природе. Вот что выдает поиск по коду плагина http://take.ms/ufRuH Есть только функция `bbp_user_login_fields()`, которая имеет совсем другое предназначение.

Answer (score 0):

В кодексе [Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User#Public_Properties) есть примечание: Если функция get_user_by() вызывается с параметром "id" или "name", конструктор запрашивает таблицу wp_users. В случае успеха дополнительные данные строки становятся свойствами объекта: user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_url, **user_registered**, user_activation_key, user_status, display_name, и их можно уже вызывать.

Что бы получить свойство user_registered, Вам нужно получить информацию об пользователе используя параметр "id" или "name".

Функции по работе с пользователями [BBPress](https://github.com/rmccue/bbPress/blob/master/bbp-includes/bbp-user-template.php)

Возможно стоит написать так:

```
$user_log = get_user_by('id', bbp_get_current_user_id());
$user_reg = $user_log->user_registered;
```

Comment: Движок wp, bbp_user_id() делает запрос в функции у bbpress. Если я предположим изменю код и сделаю вот так $user_log = get_user_by('id', '20');
$user_reg = $user_log->user_registered; То все корректно работает. Иными словами отдельно "хук" bbp_user_id() работает и выдает нужный id, но стоит его использовать в get_user_by то он не работает.

Comment: Вот код функции `bbp_user_id()` http://take.ms/q98kdU - она ничего не возвращает, а делает вывод на экран. Не надо фантазировать в ответах.

Comment: То-есть я не смогу использовать bbp_user_id(), так как она просто выводит массив на экран. А должен использовать bbp_user_login_fields()?

Comment: @All есть ещё такая функция: bbp_get_current_user_id(). Возвращает id текущего пользователя. Ответ обновил. Пробуйте

Comment: Это работает но мне нужно вытащить дату регистрации пользователя на странице профиля. А так он мне выдает данные авторизованного пользователя. Я думал что можно зацепиться за данные bbpress, так как они заполняют инфу профиля..

Comment: Что в переменной user_log?

Answer (score 0):

Вывести в профиле пользователя bbPress дату регистрации можно с помощью функции  [`bbp_displayed_user_field()`](https://bbpress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/2.5.14/includes/users/template.php#L109):

```
bbp_displayed_user_field( 'user_registered' );
```

Пример: `2017-02-28 21:31:18`.

Можно немного отформатировать результат, убрав время и оставив только дату. В этом случае нужна функция `bbp_get_displayed_user_field()`, которая не выводит значение, а возвращает в виде строки:

```
echo mysql2date( 'd.m.Y', bbp_get_displayed_user_field( 'user_registered' ) );
```

Пример: `28.02.2017`.